# Can't find angularJS libs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to front end development and learning angularJS. I have following folder structure

```
.
├── angular.min.js
├── app.js
├── bootstrap.min.css
└── index.html
```

And here is my `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="gemStore">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
    <div class="product row" ng-hide="store.product.soldOut">
        <h3>
        {{store.product.name}}
        <em class="pull-right">${{store.product.price}}</em>
    </h3>
        <button ng-show="store.product.canPurchase">Add to cart</button>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

and my `app.js` file is

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('gemStore', []);

    app.controller('StoreController', function(){
        this.products = gem;
    });

    var gem = [{
            name: 'Azurite', 
            price: 2.95,
            canPurchase: false,
            soldOut: true;
            }, {
            name: 'Azurite 2', 
            price: 2.95,
            canPurchase: false,
            soldOut: true,      
            }]
})();
```

When i open this index.html page on chrome, I don't see `angularJS` directives being replaced by real value. I haven't hosted this file on any server. As per my understanding, for html, i can just keep all the resources in relative path and the `html` file could see them. then why not here `angularJS` is able to resolve it ?

Here is my `html` output when i open it on chrome

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just forgot to include the `ngApp` directive, as below:

```
angular.module('app', [])
...

<html ng-app="app">
```

Comment: nope, it didn't make any difference. I have updated my `index.html` and also posted my `app.js` file to show what i have now. Still the same output.

Comment: I even tried with basic `{{"test"}}` output and expected to get a `test` as output on html but it didn't work.

Comment: Besides you have an array **outside** your controller, you have an extra semicolon (`;`) in your object (`soldOut: true;`), you're also trying to access `$scope.product` but you have an array called `$scope.products`, then you should use `ngRepeat` to iterate over the elements. Change it and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten the ng-repeat: you access `store.product` while you should have some wrapper element like `<div ng-repeat="product in products>` and then access directly product: `product.soldOut` or `product.canPurchase`.

Try somthing like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="gemStore">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
  <div ng-repeat="product in products>
    <div class="product row" ng-hide="product.soldOut">
        <h3>
        {{product.name}}
        <em class="pull-right">$ {{product.price}}</em>
    </h3>
        <button ng-show="product.canPurchase">Add to cart</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```